# What is the cardinality of the set $\{1, 1\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of the set $\{1, 1\}$?

My textbook does not mention this.

Comment: Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. Hence $\{1, 1\} = \{1\}$. You can take it from there.

Comment: $\{1,1\}$ does not denote a set.

Comment: @Yves: Why not?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: duplicated elements denote a multiset.

Comment: @Yves: So $\{f(n)\mid f\colon\Bbb{N\to N}, n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a multiset?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: the latter is a comprehensive definition, not an extensive one.

Comment: @Yves: I don't know what you mean by that. $\{4/2-1, |6-7|\}$ is also a multiset?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the set $A=\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 13, monkey, house, pig, 2, 6, 1, 4\right\}$ has 3 elements which are named twice, even though they do not have to be.

Think of it like this: Say I have a list of names in a classroom of 5 children. I could write that list as: $N=\left\{Puck, Elise, Mathew, George, Tim\right\}$. It wouldn't matter how often I repeat one of those names, because the same kid would just be named more often. Meaning that the set $N_2=\left\{Puck, Elise, Mathew, George, Tim, Tim, Puck, Puck, Elise\right\} = N$

This can get confusing when you start including sets in your sets. In which case you have to realise that $\left\{10\right\}\neq 10$.

This should give you plenty of information to help you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it for a minute. Your book *does not have* to mention this. It's something you can figure out for yourself.

$\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, because they're both subsets of each other and thus equal and identical. So their cardinalities are equal.

Alternatively, the function that maps $1$ to $1$ is a bijection of $\{1,1\}$ to $\{1\}$ (check it). Thus they have the same cardinality: $1$. So $\left |\{1,1\} \right |=1$.

Adam V. Nease

Comment: How would you prove that $\left\{1, 1\right\}\subseteq \left\{1\right\}$ without using that they're equal? (Or put differently: Assuming that you can't "merge" the 2 elements, so have to prove that they're both contained in $\left\{1\right\} at the same time. Seems impossible to me. (I always learned it as an Axiom as well.)

Comment: let x be in {1,1}. Then, by definition of {1,1},  x=1 or x=1. In either case, x=1. Thus, by definition of {1}, x is in {1}. Thus for all x in {1,1} x is in {1}. By the definition of subset then, {1,1}$\subseteq$ {1}.